# AvalonEdit - Style of FoldingMarker

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I activated code folding in AvalonEdit using:

```
_foldingManager = FoldingManager.Install(this.TextEditor.TextArea);
_foldingStrategy = new CSharpFoldingStrategy();
_foldingStrategy.UpdateFoldings(_foldingManager, this.TextEditor.Document);
```

Now it shows these buttons to collapse/expand blocks of code, called FoldingMarkers:

[image: AvalonEdit FoldingMarker]

There are some members in the ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Folding namespace, such as:
[ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Folding.FoldingMargin.FoldingMarkerBrush](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/?topic=html/57730fc8-c950-22d6-1668-b6aad059ce18.htm)

But I can't find a way to reach these properties.

How to change FoldingMarkers colors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got these properties calling FoldingMargin statically:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
var back = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));
var hover = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(60, 60, 60));
var fore = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(100, 100, 100));

FoldingMargin.SetFoldingMarkerBackgroundBrush(Editor, back);
FoldingMargin.SetSelectedFoldingMarkerBackgroundBrush(Editor, hover);
FoldingMargin.SetFoldingMarkerBrush(Editor, fore);
FoldingMargin.SetSelectedFoldingMarkerBrush(Editor, fore);
```